# At all of these aspects VS in all these aspects

Tags: grammaticality

Let's say you want to talk about similarities that chess and life have in common, and how different aspects that apply to one thing also apply to the other.

1. "In chess as in life, you will need to be good **at all of these** aspects to win."
2. "In chess as in life, you will need to be good **in all these** aspects to win."

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: "good in" doesn't seem idiomatic. "good at" is.

Comment: Thank you so muh

Answer (score -1):

No-one could ever be good 'at' an aspect, if for no other reason than that 'aspect', as any other '…spect' basically describes a 'view.'  Consider 'inspect' or 'respect' or what have you.

Would '… you will need to be good at all (of) these respects…" work for you?

Would '… you will need to be good in all (of) these respects…" be better?

Comment: There are certainly Google hits for "good at all aspects" and similar phrases, including from [John Cleese](https://time.com/3560463/10-questions-with-john-cleese/) who is quite well-educated.

Comment: Thanks and roughly what credence do you give to Google in general, particularly when you chose not to Post the search criteria? Why not mention some specific examples thrown up by Google?